# Extract HTML Tags using preg_split

Tags: php, regex

i have a string

```
$string = 'this is test <b>bold</b> this is another test <img src="#"> image' ;
```

i want split html tag alone & normal text alone.

need the following output like :

```
[0] => this is test
[1] => <b>bold</b>
[2] => this is another test
[3] => <img src="#">
[4] => image
```

using this code.

```
$strip = preg_split('/\s+(?![^<>]+>)/m', $string , -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) ;
```

output.

```
[0] => this
[1] => is
[2] => test
[3] => <b>bold</b>
[4] => this
[5] => .....
```

i'm newbie. pls help!

Comment: Can you clarify what your end goal is?

Comment: hi. i need following output.

[0] => this is test
[1] => <b>bold</b>
[2] => this is another test
[3] => <img src="#">
[4] => image

Comment: You are trying to parse HTML with regex - don't, use a proper HTML parser, [PHP has several](http://stackoverflow.com/q/292926/107152).

Comment: There is no consistent pattern you can follow in your string / matching. How to differ between text inside a tag and next to a tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it easier to get that result using `preg_match`:

```
$string = 'this is test <b>bold</b> this is another test <img src="#"> image <hr/>';
preg_match_all('/<([^\s>]+)(.*?)>((.*?)<\/\1>)?|(?<=^|>)(.+?)(?=$|<)/i',$string,$result);
$result = $result[0];
// assign the result to the variable
foreach ($result as &$group) {
    $group = preg_replace('/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/','$1',$group);
    // this is to eliminate preceding and trailing spaces
}
print_r($result);
```

**EDIT:**

I was assuming there should be at least 1 character in between the opening and the closing of a tag, but it's not necessary so I changed the second `+` into an `*` and I took into account the possibility of case insensitivity in tags.

**Output:**

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => this is test
>     [1] => <b>bold</b>
>     [2] => this is another test
>     [3] => <img src="#">
>     [4] => image
>     [4] => <hr/>
> )
> ```

### EDIT 2:

This won't work with irregular situations such as thode exemplified in the comments:

`foo<b>bar<i>ital</b>ic</i>` or `foo<b>bar<b>baz</b>fail</b>`

To make it work the RegEx should be tweaked to look inside the matches and process them accordingly.

Comment: Check the revised lines that eliminates the preceding/trailing spaces in each group. You're welcome btw.

Comment: i think because html is wrong. 

foo<b>bar</b><b>baz</b><b>fail</b>

Comment: The following won't work either - `foo<b>bar<i>ital</b>ic</i>`

Comment: @Bhawna Kumar: `<b><b>hello</b> world </b>` is not wrong HTML. It's more tags than necessary but it's not wrong.