# How can i explode or preg split using html tags as a delimiter

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
<h1 class="x">asd</h1><h1 class="y">zxcasd</h1>
```

how can i use explode or preg split, so that it becomes an array like so, where it only splits between h1 tags:

```
0 => <h1 class="x">asd</h1>

1 => <h1 class="y">zxcasd</h1>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract HTML Tags using preg\_split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762752/extract-html-tags-using-preg-split)

Comment: sorry, there was a formatting error in the question, unfortunately your suggestion didnt help, i have updated the question so it should make more sense now.

Comment: Have you even opened the link and checked it? It gives you exactly what you want, copy and paste the code provided in the answer and replace `$string` with the value `'<h1 class="x">asd</h1><h1 class="y">zxcasd</h1>'`? How does this not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would use `preg_match_all` as opposed to `explode|preg_split`...

```
preg_match_all($regex, $input, $output);
```

Secondly, you need to define your capture group. I.e. a pattern which matches your intended content...

```
#<h1.*?>.*?</h1>#
#                  : Starting delimiter
 <h1               : Literal match
    .*?            : Matches any character 0 or more times in a non-greedy manner (eats class=".." and other attributes; stops matching at first instance of next character)
       >           : Literal match
        .*?        : Matches any character 0 or more times in a non-greedy manner
           </h1>   : Literal match
                #  : Ending delimiter
```

Third, put it into code...

```
$input = '<h1 class="x">asd</h1><h1 class="y">zxcasd</h1>';

preg_match_all('#<h1.*?>.*?</h1>#', $input, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);

/* Output:

Array
    (
        [0] => <h1 class="x">asd</h1>
        [1] => <h1 class="y">zxcasd</h1>
    )

*/
```

**N.B.**

This won't match badly formatted `html`, you may need to change your regex if it doesn't match as intended. For example:

```
#<h1[^<>]*?>.*?</h1>#  >> Prevents matching all of: <h1 </h1><h1> </h1>
#<h1.*?>.*?</h1\s*>#   >> Matches with a spaces after closing h1: </h1   >
```